# Show overflowing div over top an image

Tags: html, css

I have a div, `.top-level-object`, that overflows both of its containers, `.tl-object-container` and `.header`. My goal is to have `.top-level-object` visible and in front of all other elements in this scenario. I've tried z-indexing, but I couldn't get it to work. The image, for some reason is the only thing with this kind of behavior, because if you remove it, you will clearly see that the example works.

**Side Note**: I can't set `position:absolute;` on `.top-level-object` because other objects on the page depend on the space that it takes up for formatting.

What could I be missing?

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
}
.tl-object-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1px;
  float: right;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
}
.top-level-object {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
}
.object-covering-tl-object {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.object-covering-tl-object img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.object-not-being-covered-by-tl-object {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="tl-object-container">
    <div class="top-level-object">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="object-covering-tl-object">
  <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/home/01.jpg" alt="Random Image" />
</div>
<div class="object-not-being-covered-by-tl-object">

</div>
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` isn't necessarily required to be able to use `z-index` - you can set `position: relative;` and adjust `z-index`.

Comment: @Toby, I know. That was just a side note. But I still can't get it to work, unless you have a working example....?

Comment: I apologize - I'm having trouble visualizing what you're trying to achieve - can you tell me what works and doesn't work here? I've added borders and changed the opacity levels to make it clearer to me. http://jsbin.com/yewajen/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Toby Wow WTF?!?! Would you like to answer, or should I delete the question? I guess I was moving too many parts around at the same time...

Comment: Lol.. I answered, it'd be great if you could accept the answer, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `position: relative;` you can then adjust `z-index` - the difference being that the position is adjusted based upon the position of the element if it were static, as opposed to being "absolute" to a parent element.